# Azure The application must write data to the company's directory by using the Directory.ReadWrite.All permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

**A company plans to deploy a non-interactive daemon app to their Azure tenant.**

**The application must write data to the company’s directory by using the Directory.ReadWrite.All permission. The application must not prompt users for consent.**

**You need to grant the access required by the application.**

**Which permission should you use?**

Select only one answer.

1. admin-restricted
2. delegated
3. application
4. effective

Comment: what is the answer of it?

Comment: It's #3 application permissions. [refer link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview)